# hidding errors when sqlsrv_fetch_array return nothing

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I reading records from db. But when my query fail i have errors exmp : Undefined variable. I know thats normal becouse query cant find nothing in db. How to hide errors? I trying this:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "MY SQL QUERY WHERE status='running'))");

if ($result === false) {
    $note = 'unknown';
    $code = 'unknown';


    } else { 

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
  {

    $note = $row['note'];
    $code = $row['code'];   
  }

}
echo $note;
echo $code;
```

Logicly should be good?

Comment: What do you want to echo if there are no results?

Comment: i put IF statement and $note = 'unknown';
    $code = 'unknown';
if no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no results then `$result` is not false but there are no rows. You can get round this by setting the `$note` and `$code` variables to a default first:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "MY SQL QUERY WHERE status='running'))");

$note = 'unknown';
$code = 'unknown';
if ($result !== false) {
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $note = $row['note'];
        $code = $row['code'];   
    }
}
echo $note;
echo $code;
```